# duplicate values after distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to get from 3 tables the data on specific bus number on specific time but the result not make any sense...

My script is:

```
SELECT 
    distinct b.OraReg as date_and_time,
    b.IdMezzo as bus_number, b.StatoPorte as open_doors,
    b.speed as speed, lc.codazultimafermata as platform_number,
    n.descrnodo as platform_name
FROM 
    table 1 as b
INNER JOIN
    table 2 lc ON lc.id = b.IdMezzo
INNER JOIN
    table 3 n ON n.codaznodo = lc.codazultimafermata
WHERE
    b.OraReg BETWEEN '2016-08-21 14:24:00' AND '2016-08-21 14:29:30' 
    AND b.IdMezzo = 17  
    AND lc.codazultimafermata IN ('47487', '47537') 
    AND lc.orainvio BETWEEN '2016-08-21 14:24:00' AND '2016-08-21 14:29:30'
ORDER BY
    b.OraReg
```

My result got duplicated value for each row although I did it with distinct... What am I doing wrong ?

```
date_and_time   bus_number  open_doors  speed   platform_number
---------------------------------------------------------------
24:01.1         17          0           0       47487
24:01.1         17          0           0       47537
24:16.8         17          0           32      47487
24:16.8         17          0           32      47537
24:21.3         17          0           41      47487
24:21.3         17          0           41      47537
24:47.8         17          0           54      47487
24:47.8         17          0           54      47537
25:10.9         17          0           9       47487
25:10.9         17          0           9       47537
25:26.6         17          0           41      47487
25:26.6         17          0           41      47537
25:42.1         17          0           5       47487
25:42.1         17          0           5       47537
25:44.9         17          1           0       47487


tables structure - 
 table 1 - 
 OraReg datetime    Checked
 IdMezzo    int Unchecked
 StatoPorte tinyint Checked
 speed  tinyint Checked

 table 2 - 

 dataora    datetime    Unchecked
 codazultimafermata int Checked


 table 3 - 
 cinnodo    int Unchecked
 codaznodo  int Checked
 descrnodo  varchar(50) Checked
```

Comment: I see no duplicate rows.

Comment: looks like each of the times is joining to both of the platforms, is there anyway you can make platform number a joining value between two of the 3 tables? can we see table structures?

Comment: please show, what your problem is in detail. the shown result has no duplicates in terms of sqlserver. the distinct is running as expected

Comment: @Tzahi Kadosh `DISTINCT` works on a row basis, not on a column basis.

Comment: Your `date_and_time` `bus_number` `open_doors` and `speed` values are the same, but your `platform_number` is different. You have a cross join between `table1` and `table2`.

Comment: hi ... it's weird because same bus on same hour cannot be in 2 different places... from my point of view it's cannot be right because all data came from bus's computer.

Comment: show us the table structure of the 3 tables and we can work out what is missing from the join.

Comment: hi, i updated my question with the tables structure

Comment: Show us some of the source data too

Comment: Perhaps provide the relevant data for bus 17 as it pertains to the results above using VALUE statements. I would suspect that one of your joins is incorrect, but without understanding the underlying data it is a little difficult to determine.

Comment: "same bus on same hour cannot be in 2 different places" - include the datetime column in join condition then (and b.orareg = lc.dataora)